# Set properties in nested class at runtime

Tags: c#

I'm taking a course in C# and just started to play around with reflection.
I'm trying to build a model that I use in a Win Forms app. The model looks like this (but with more _value:s and other stuff).

```
public class ParentClass
{
    private int _id;
    private string _value1, _value2, _value3;
    private Random _random;
    private List<string> _registryStuff;
    private User _user;
    private ChildClass1 _childClass1;
    private ChildClass2 _childClass2;


    public ParentClass()
    {
        _user = new User();
        _random = new Random();
        _childClass1 = new ChildClass1();
        _childClass2 = new ChildClass2();
    }

    public User User
    {
        get => _user;
        set => _user = value;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id; set => _id = _random.Next(1, 100);
    }

    public string Value1
    {
        get => _value1; set => _value1 = _childClass1.Method()[1];
    }

    public string Value2
    {
        get => _value2; set => _value2 = _childClass1.Method()[2];
    }

    public string Value3
    {
        get => _value3; set => _value3 = _childClass1.Method()[3];
    }

    public List<string> RegistryStuff
    {
        get => _registryStuff; set => _registryStuff = GetData();
    }

    private List<string> GetData()
    {
        List<string> keys = new List<string>()
        {
            @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall",
            @"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
        };

        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        return _childClass2.Method(RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, 
        RegistryView.Registry64), keys, result);
    }
}

// ChildClass1.cs
public class ChildClass1
{
    public string[] Method()
    { 
        //... do stuff...
        // return the string array from there
    }
}

// ChildClass2.cs
public class ChildClass2
{
    public List<string> Method(RegistryKey regKey, List<string> keys, List<string> result)
    { 
        //... do stuff..
        // return the List from there
    }
}
```

---

How can I set _id, _value1, _value2, _value3 etc at runtime? Is it even possible this way?
The ParentClass.User.Value1, Value2 etc is set via textboxes in the form.

My thought was I could use reflection to set the values.

This works if I change the props to something like: `get => _childClass1.Method()[1]; set => _value1 = value;` and then use a method like this when I want to populate a data grid in the form.

```
    private static DataTable CreateTable(object obj, DataGridView grid)
    {
        DataTable _dTable = new DataTable();
        DataRow _dRow = _dTable.NewRow();

        grid.DataSource = _dTable;
        grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

        _dTable.Rows.Add(_dRow);
        _dTable.Columns.Add("PropName", typeof(string));
        _dTable.Columns.Add("PropType", typeof(string));
        _dTable.Columns.Add("PropValue", typeof(string));

        obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(prop =>
        {
            try
            {
                _dTable.Rows.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType, prop.GetValue(obj));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }
        });

        return _dTable;
    }
```

Comment: The fact that all your setters ignore the value passed to them is really, really odd... (And your `User` property can be just automatically-implemented...)

Comment: So how do I solve it ?

Comment: Given that your design for properties is so unusual (ignoring whatever is passed to the setter) we can't really tell what "solving" means...